# Cannot access or update atom from within a seesaw listener function

Tags: clojure, seesaw

I have a seesaw ui with a text editor. The editor content is backed by a record called 'Task' which is contained somewhere in an atom called 'state'. A key-released event on the editor should change the property :desc of the Task. I use the following code:

```
(def state
     (atom {:tasks []
            :interval nil
            :style (style :foreground :black :background nil)}))

(defn on-text-edited [ui listener-fn]
  (let [editor (select ui [:#editor])]  
    (listen editor :key-released
        (fn [evt] (listener-fn (text editor))))))

(defn update-task! [task text]
  (let [newtask (assoc task :desc text)
        tasks (replace {task newtask} (:tasks @state))]
  (swap! state
     #(assoc % :tasks tasks))))

(def text-updates (on-text-edited frame #(update-task! selected-task %)))
```

*selected-task* is an atom referencing the current content model of the editor. Whenever the user edits text the update-task! function is supposed to be called. But nothing happens. The function seems not to be called at all. When I call it from the repl it behaves as expected.

I tested if the function would get called by letting it do a simple println:

```
(defn update-task! [task text]
   (println (str task " " text)))
```

Now the function works fine when I edit text in the editor. Then I changed it to:

```
(defn update-task! [task text]
  (let [newtask (assoc task :desc text)
        tasks (replace {task newtask} (:tasks @state))]
     (println (str task " " text))))
```

now again, it would do nothing at all. So it seems that somehow the accessing of the atoms get in the way of the event handling. Is there maybe a conflict between the ui thread and the thread the atoms were defined in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a case like this where it works in the simple case and stops in a more complex case, I'd guess that there's an exception occurring, probably in `assoc` or `replace` in the `let` bindings. Depending on your dev environment, the exception may be hidden since it happens on the UI thread.

I'd suggest try calling `seesaw.dev/debug!` which will popup a ui with a stack trace whenever an unhandled exception is thrown in the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were right. Setting debug revealed a stupid mistake I made. Tried to access an atom where I should have accessed its value instead.